# WatchOS - App Store doesn't list localised languages for standalone watch app

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, app-store, watchos

I have a standalone Apple Watch app, and localised it to many languages, also localised the App Store product pages.
Everything works great, app and store page shows in the correct language, but the language section on the store only lists English.

[image: App Store page]

[image: Xcode]

This is most likely a problem (wouldn't be the first) with standalone watch apps, but is there something I can do other than adding an iPhone app?

Answer (score 0):

Added the Localizable.string file to the base app target (first one before WatchKit app and WatchKit Extension) and now it works.